# File not found java

Tags: java, file, exception

I have a problem when reading a text file in java. The class is  ***FlashCardReader*** and I have the following constructor that handles the part of the reading.

```
public FlashCardReader( String fileName ) {
    try{

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("The file was not found or the name may be wrong!");
    }
}
```

My main method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FlashCardReader fcr = new FlashCardReader("Questions.txt");
}
```

And the final output is: ***The file was not found or the name may be wrong!***

[image]

Some help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Comment: well, your Questions.txt is in src folder, I doubt your java program is executed from this folder. Add full path to this file and it should work.

Comment: @marcinj I am sorry what do you mean by "I doubt your java program is executed from this folder". I can send you a picture and show that they are all in the same directory.

Comment: Usually IDE-s will generate .class files in a build folder and execute them from this folder.

Comment: To figure out the absolute path where the FileReader is seeking use `File.getAbsolutePath()` method. E.g:

`File reader = new File(fileName); `

`System.out.println(reader.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: @DmitryBogdanovich cheers, but if the file is pointing to null how would the IDE know the path of the file? Because my problem was getting a Null pointer to that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the current directory of your java program where it is executed from with this java code,

```
System.out.println("CurrentDir: " + (new File(".").getCanonicalPath()));
```

Say it prints,

```
CurrentDir: D:\pkr\test
```

Then you can correctly choose a path through which your file can be correctly located.

Most likely, your `src` folder should be in `test` directory and in that case you can either move your file from `src` folder to `test` folder or refer your file in your code like this,

`..\\Questions.txt`

which should be able to read your file.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks i found out that my folder was laying in another folder which is actually  quite odd, haha. Cheers!